# Angular navigating from AppComponent to another Component

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio

I have the following setup:
in app-routing module:

```
export const routes: Routes = [  
  { path: '',  component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'Role', component: RoleComponent }
];
```

In app.module.ts, I have:

```
imports: [    
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
```

In app.component.html, I have

Test

view above is an iframe. However, it doesn't find the role component to go to role.component.html page and open it in iframe.
BTW, role component files are in a folder called role under app directory where the app.component.html is.
app > app.component.html, ts, css
app > role > role.component.html, ts, css

And obviously everything compiles fine in VS Code.

Any ideas whats missing?

Comment: "it doesn't find the role component" - did you add the `RoleComponent` to the declarations array of your module?

Comment: Off course I did. Sorry did not mention that. I just showed the route registration in the app module.

Comment: I'm not sure about the capital letters in routes, try it with `role`, and navigate to `localhost:4200/role`

Comment: I tried role, did not make a difference...and yes, localhost:4200/role is what I am using. thanks.